# Homology defining quasi-isomorphisms vs sheaf cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors, derived-categories

I don’t understand how the homology groups in regards to the derived category of sheafs on a space X is connected to the cohomology of a sheaf which is calculated with the images/kernels after applying the global sections functor. As we have a quasi-isomorphism between sheaf complexes if the homology groups (which are calculated with images/kernels of maps of sheafs - not global sections) are isomorphic.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're confusing the cohomology of a complex with the cohomology of a sheaf. Let me see if there's a reasonable duplicate around.

Comment: @KReiser thanks